# jQuery Colorbox iframe not using post

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, iframe, colorbox

I am using jquery to override form submit. Then calling colorbox with iframe true and setting data as object. Since colorbox uses load for ajax calls setting data attribute as an object should use post submit method. However it is not. Is there a way to accomplish this?

```
$("#checkout_form").submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();

var data = $.parseJSON($(this).find("[name=payload]").attr("value"));

$.colorbox({
    href:$(this).attr("action"), 
    width:'600', 
    height:'450',
    iframe:true,
    data:data,
    overlayClose:false
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say, colorbox doesnt use `.load()` to populate the `iframe` . 
It sets the `iframes` `src` attribute .
Hence you cant post data, only use URL parameters to pass data.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update, here is the code provided by [Erik Petersen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1356766/erik-petersen). I tested it myself and works fine.

```
function updateFolderCate(ID,Type){
    $.colorbox({
        open: true,
        scrolling: false,
        innerWidth:'100',
        innerHeight:'100',
        href:"page.php",
        data:{LinkID:ID,itemType:Type},
        onClosed:function(){
            //Do something on close.
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You should be able to modify this to accomplish what you're trying to do.